# Why VS render CSS correctly only after hot-reload?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, layout, scroll

I am confused by the behavior of the website I develop.
I use newest Visual Studio and ASP.NET Core, so HTML and CSS writing .cshtml and .css files at the moment.

**Problem:**

It renders broken at first:

[image]

but when I do any change in runtime to the related css class in site.css file (global css) and save the file, then it renders it correctly (you can find that notes are under the green and red lines). Change in this case was 99% instead 100% of width.

[image]

**Questions:**

Do I do something wrong in code or the ISS / VS / HotReload have some bug?

What would be the output of compiled code then?

**Code:**

site.css:

```
.detailsContainer {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    max-height: 80%;
    width: 99%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.scrollContainer {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex: 1;
}

.scrollContainerNotes {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex: 1;
}
```

my cleaned view:

```
<h1>Details</h1>
<div class="detailsContainer">

    <div>
        <table class="table">
            ...
        </table>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scrollContainer">
        <div>
            <div class="scroll">
                <ol class="altrow">
                    @foreach (UploadDetails line in Model.Details)
                    {
                       ...
                    }
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollContainerNotes">
        <hr />
        <h4>Notes</h4>
        <div class="scroll">
            <ul>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit - Solution:**

As @VDWWD has mentioned in the comment - it was browser caching. CTRL + F5 on the broken page fixed the issue.

Comment: A css file is stored in the browser cache. So press Control + F5 to reload all items in the cache for a specific page.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Indeed, it was browser caching. 
Have a nice day!